# Use UIImagePickerController in landscape mode in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am coding a LandScape only iPad application and i need to take pictures from library to send a database but image upload screen only works on Portrait mode. How do i change it to landscape mode? I've read something about UIPickerControllerDelegate doesn't support the Landscape mode but some of the apps ( such as iMessage ) is already using this.

here is my code:

```
class signUpViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    print("Image Selected")

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    profileImageView.image = image

}



@IBAction func importImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It absolutely supports landscape mode. Put this extension somewhere. Best in a file named UIImagePickerController+SupportedOrientations.swift

```
extension UIImagePickerController
{
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape
    }
}
```

This makes all UIImagePickerControllers in your app landscape. You can also subclass it and override this method to make only a subclass landscape-able:

```
class LandscapePickerController: UIImagePickerController
{
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape
    }
}
```

Finally, to support all orientations you can return

```
return [.Landscape, .Portrait]
```

**For Swift 3:**

```
    extension UIImagePickerController
    {
        override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
                return true
        }
        override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
                return .all
        }
}
```

Comment: In order to work this, i have to Enable Portrait mode, but my application doesn't support it so that i can't enable it.  Code works in landscape mode if portrait mode is enabled but When i disable portrait mode, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have added override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    } This to every viewcontroller, its bad but usefull solution. Do you have any other idea? Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you know how to redraw the cells after rotation? Cause now my detail disclosure icons have too much inset from the right side...

Comment: Documentation for UIImagePickerController indicates that it should not be subclassed. "The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller