# Landscape orientation lock not working when trying to open photo gallery Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, landscape, sigabrt, nsexception

I am making an app that allows the user to open the photo gallery to change a picture in an image view. Whenever I lock the orientation to landscape mode, to avoid gross constraints and the app overall shoving everything I love off the screen, the photo gallery tries to open in portrait mode. To fix this I made a new class called UIImagePickerController+SupportedOrientations and added

```
extension UIImagePickerController
{
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape
    }
    override public func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool { return false }
}
```

to hopefully stop this. Now it opens in landscape mode whenever I use the app without locking it, but if I lock it I get the following error

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Does it causing crash? or just a warning in your debugger?

Comment: Its causing a full crash whenever I attempt to open the photo gallery @AKMSalehSultan

Comment: Ok give an hour. Let me get back to you soon.

Answer (score -1):

It absolutely supports landscape mode. Put this extension somewhere. Best in a file named UIImagePickerController+SupportedOrientations.swift

```html
extension UIImagePickerController
{
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape
    }
}
```

This makes all UIImagePickerControllers in your app landscape. You can also subclass it and override this method to make only a subclass landscape-able:

```html
class LandscapePickerController: UIImagePickerController
{
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape
    }
}
```

Finally, to support Landscape orientations you can return

```html
return [.Landscape]
```

Comment: -1  This solution is a copy of the answer provided in: Use UIImagePickerController in landscape mode in Swift 2.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058691/use-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-mode-in-swift-2-0)